# Completion of $C_{0,rad}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ with respect to the norm $\|u\|= \Bigg(\int_{\Omega} |\Delta u |^2 \, \mathrm{d}x \Bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}. $

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-pde

I have a question that it seems simple but I can not solve it.

Let $\Omega$ be the unit ball centered at zero in $\mathbb{R}^N$, $N>4$. Assume that $C_{0,rad}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is the space of all radial symmetric smooth functions with compact support.

> What is the completion of $C_{0,rad}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ with respect to the following norm
>
> $$\|u\|= \Bigg(\int_{\Omega} |\Delta u |^2 \, \mathrm{d}x \Bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}. $$
>
> Is it $W_0^{2,2}(\Omega)$ or $W_{0,rad}^{2,2}(\Omega)$.

I think that the answer is $W_0^{2,2}(\Omega)$ but I have no idea to prove it.

I will be thanked to any useful hint or answer.

Comment: I don't see how it can possibly be $W^{2,2}_0(\Omega)$.  For instance, the completion certainly can't contain any function whose Laplacian isn't radially symmetric.

Comment: Maybe you already know that, but by integration by parts your norm is equal to $\left(\int_\Omega|D^2u|^2dx\right)^{1/2}$ since $\langle \nabla u,\nabla\Delta u\rangle=-|D^2u|^2+\tfrac{1}{2}\Delta|\nabla u|^2$ where $|D^2u|^2$ is the Frobenius norm of the Hessian.

Comment: Thomas's remark, along with the definitions of the two spaces you're trying to decide between, immediately gives the answer. This is more appropriate for math.stackexchange.com